# Webpack/babel Unexpected token, expected ";"

Tags: node.js, json, webpack

I'm trying to import a JSON file, but when I attempt to load my JSON file webpack gives me an error.

> ERROR in ./src/testData.json
>   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
>   SyntaxError: C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Work\test-app\learn-fullstack-javascript\src\testData.json: Unexpected token, expected ";" (3:12)

I've tried changing my babel and webpack configuration files, but haven't been able to fix the issue.

Here are my config files: 
webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
      path: __dirname + '/public',
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx|json)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets:['@babel/preset-env']
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  };
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/react'],
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

lastly my package.json

```
{
  "name": "learjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "For an up-to-date configuration guide: [jscomplete.com/reactful](https://jscomplete.com/reactful)",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node server.js --ignore public/",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/jscomplete/learn-fullstack-javascript.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/jscomplete/learn-fullstack-javascript/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/jscomplete/learn-fullstack-javascript#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel-preset-node7": "^1.5.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.4.0",
    "braces": "^2.3.2",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "mongodb": "^3.2.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "@babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "@babel-jest": "^24.7.1",
    "@babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.6",
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/node": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.11",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.2",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0"
  }
}
```

```
{
  "contests": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "categoryName": "Business/Company",
      "contestName": "Cognitive Building Bricks"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "categoryName": "Magazine/Newsletter",
      "contestName": "Educating people about sustainable food production"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "categoryName": "Software Component",
      "contestName": "Big Data Analytics for Cash Circulation"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "categoryName": "Website",
      "contestName": "Free programming books"
    }
  ]
}
```

I was expecting to get something like this inside of chrome dev tools.

```
Object i
  contents: Array[4]
  > 0: Object
  > .......
```

Comment: You've left out the file we need to see the most: `testData.json`, the one the error message specifically points to. :-) Apparently it has a `;` in it. It shouldn't (outside of a string), JSON doesn't use `;` for anything.

Comment: oh man i overlooked that ;/ , just added the json file to the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try taking out the `json` from your webpack config. You don't need babel-loader to handle json, you can use json-loader for that

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
      path: __dirname + '/public',
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets:['@babel/preset-env']
            }
          }
        },
        {
          test:  /\.json$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            // included by default (https://webpack.js.org/loaders/json-loader/)
            loader: 'json-loader' 
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  };
```

Comment: you're a beautiful person! This worked great! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Glad it worked out! If you like, you can select this as your answer, and I will get points.

Comment: For me, taking out the `json` from the webpack config was enough. I did not have to use `json-loader`. As far as I understand it, Webpack does this out of the box now.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you just need to delete jsx and json from `test: /\.(js|jsx|json)$/` in your webpack.config.json file

```
 rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets:['@babel/preset-env']
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Please try to explain your answers so that others can learn from them.

Comment: Actually I don't know why this happens. I had the exact same proplem and I'm new to react. I guess there is a conflict between jsx and json, and json files shouldn't be handled with babel-loader.